# The FAQ doesn't discuss answering

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, answers, faq-suggestion

When looking for a link to give to someone new to the site about what kind of answers we look for I noticed the [FAQ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/faq) talks a lot about how to ask good questions but not about good answers.

Kind of a strange omission since it's actually good answers that folks are after. Even stranger that it took me 18 months to notice!

I wonder if it would be useful to have a series of before and after examples to show. For example:

> Q: Where can i find Yak migration data?
>
> Poor A: Yakyaka.com has a ton of great data, have you tried there?
>
> Better A: Yakyaka.com has an archive going back to 1764, though the
>   period from 1812-1855 is a bit sketchy. For quick overview of the
>   holdings see the [online map viewer] and the raw .csv and shapefiles
>   are on their [ftp site]. Note the data is free but commercial use
>   requires permission (usually easily granted).

Comment: Sounds good to me. How do we go about updating the FAQ?

Comment: Along those lines, the FAQ examples and screenshots are from the Bicycles.se site, can these also be tailored to GIS.se?

Comment: Mods can edit only the first section of the FAQ, which is the text spanning (but *not* including) "What kind of questions can I ask here?" and "Please look around to see if your question has been asked before...".  Changing anything else might require a system-wide modification!  I have added the [tag:feature-request] tag to see whether we can get someone from SE to weigh in.

Comment: @ChadCooper what examples and screenshots are you referring to? Thanks for mentioning Bicycles.se, I hadn't run into it yet. They have an interesting take on how to build a [terminology page](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index) which might be worth emulating.

Comment: @mattwilkie - look at the [How to ask questions here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) section for a bicyles screenshot.

Comment: The FAQ link has for many years redirected to the [Tour] so, while the intent of this question is important, I think its text needs to be heavily revised.

Answer (score 4):

The new [help center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help) page now addresses answering.

[How do I write a good answer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section is a start link one can provide for new users.

Additionally, we might consider building a GIS Meta thread with specific guidelines to improve answering on GIS SE.

> How to answer on GIS SE?

We already started this with questions:

[What makes a good question?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-makes-a-good-question)

As these kind of threads become mature, they can evolve to a FAQ status.
For example, in Cross Validated Meta, there are specific [how to ask](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated) and [how to answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/how-should-questions-be-answered-on-cross-validated) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) threads.